# The generating function of sequence $a_n$ is known. How to evaluate the number (or density) of term "0" in $\{a_n\}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

If the generating function of $\{a_n\}$ is $\displaystyle A(x)=\sum^\infty_{k=0}a_kx^k$, how can we use $A(x)$ to calculate or estimate the number (or density) of term "0" in $\{a_n\}$?

Comment: Hello :) it is $A(0) =a_0$.

Comment: [Harder than it seems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_problem).